# What is the best and the efficient way of tracking whether Apache web server is up and running?

Tags: shell-script, centos, apache-httpd, ps, ss

When I wanted to check whether the Apache web server is up and running on the linux server(CentOS), I came to two solutions by tracking through the `ps` command and `ss` command. Following I've tried:

```
ps -aux | grep httpd
ss -tulwn | grep LISTEN | grep 80
```

**Note:** I have installed Apache using generic binaries and haven't created the `systemd` configuration files. Because I'm not expecting to use the command:

```
systemctl status httpd
```

So, what may be the effective and efficient method of tracking the active status or whether Apache web server is installed on the linux server.

Comment: Finding the best (of anything), is very high complexity. Even after finding it, it is near impossible to verify. (see travelling sales man problem). Have you a better criteria? What is good enough?

Comment: Since only you know how it was installed, only you know how to check whether it *is* installed. `ps` is the way to check whether it is running. Or create a systemd unit file (you can install httpd on a different server and use the unit file for inspiration) and use `systemctl status`.

Answer (score 4):

Knowing that a server is up. Is not sufficient to know that it is performing its service. Therefore forget checking that the process is running. Instead see if you can get it to do some work.

I.e. Request a web page from it.

Comment: It is regarding the best method to track whether the Apache server is running or installed. Not about the performance about the Apache server. So could you please provide what will be effective in this @ctrl-alt-delor

Comment: On Centos, `rpm -qa | grep httpd` to check if it is installed, and `systemctl status httpd` if it is running.

Comment: @berndbausch although OP stated *"Because I'm not expecting to use the command `systemctl status httpd`"*.

Comment: To check if the binary exists, something like: `find /usr/sbin -type f -name "apache2" -exec grep -IL . "{}" \;`

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Thanks for pointing this out. I managed to forget this.

Comment: @Aravinda my answer is not about performance. I is to check that the service is running (as asked for). It dose not check to see if a process is being used, or memory is being used, or the CPU is being consumed.

Answer (score 2):

It depends to what level you want to know.

To really check if it works, use

```
if curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail "$url"; then
  echo yes
else
  echo no
fi
```

If you're not interested in specific pages, you might just:

```
if curl -s url ; then 
    echo jes
else 
    echo no
fi
```

If you want to know that apache listens to a port,

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
```

gives you that information.

If you want to know if the process runs,

```
if ps -aux | grep 'http[d]' ; then
    echo yes
else 
    echo no
fi
```

should do the trick.